# NGINX reverse proxy to node HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I've got an NGINX server running a reverse-proxy server to a node app.
Now I need to get it working with https but I keep getting 502: Bad Gateway error when trying to access the site at https

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MYSERVERDOMAIN;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name MYSERVERDOMAIN;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setting looks correct, so I'm not quite sure about the issue. However, I'm using below setting for my production server with additional config for `static assets` folder and `https` auto-forward - which is the ultimate settings you may want for your `production servers`. Hope that it can help:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
        server_name example.com;

        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.chained.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com_ssl_private_key.key;

        root /var/www/example/public;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Comment: cool thanks. due to look at this today so this is helpful. The SSL problem I had was config problem with the wider network